# Must child classes implement protocols to which their parents conform?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, subclassing

I have a class, `MyClass`, which implements the `NSCopying` protocol, and I have a class, `MyClassChild`, which inherits from `MyClass`. `MyClassChild` does not implement the `NSCopying` protocol. The textbook I am reading says it must, however I can build successfully! Is the textbook wrong?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSCopying> {

}

@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;
}

@end

@interface MyClassChild : MyClass {

}

@end

@implementation MyClassChild

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don’t supply an implementation for the `copyWithZone:` method in `MyClassChild`, the class inherits the method implementation from its superclass (`MyClass`). This means that `MyClassChild` *does* conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. If `MyClassChild` needs to do something special when its instances are being copied, you should override `copyWithZone:` and do whatever needs to be done there. Hope that helps.

P.S. I hope you realize that returning `self` is not a good way to implement `copyWithZone:`?

Comment: +1 Missed that.  It's not "not good", it's plain wrong (except in a GC environment).  You need to at least return `[self retain];` and then only for immutable objects.

Comment: yeah was just to compile it quickly

Answer (score 1):

`MyClassChild` inherits its implementation of `NSCopying` from `MyClass`.  Even if you had specified

```
@interface MyClassChild : MyClass <NSCopying>
```

the compiler is clever enough to check if any of the super classes implement `-copyWithZone:`

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right that `NSCopying` requires the object to implement `copyWithZone`. However, `MyClass` implements `copyWithZone`. So `MyClassChild` already an implementation of it by virtue of deriving from `MyClass`.

Comment: -1 NSObject does not implement `-copyWithZone:` which is the important method.  It does implement `+copyWithZone:` but that is a class method.

Comment: Ouch, you are quite right. I didn't even answer the question properly either.